# How to manage the same database from different classes? (android/sqlite)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

**In my android app I had one class doing the following functions:**
*storing data from an XML source into a database;*
*loading the data from the database;*
*rewriting to the database from the xml source if the data was more than 24 hours old;*
that all worked fine.

**I am now trying to write a new table to that same database from another class.**
So I followed the same procedures/set-up as in the first class and now the program crashes (force close error) and the android log cat gives the following errors:
*SQL error: msg= table "table-name" does not exist*
*error inserting (query) into table "table-name"* (this error is repeated for each insert attempted)

The problem is, the "table-name" it gives me (saying it doesn't exist) is the table from the first class which worked fine before.

Here is some relevant code:

```
public class CurrencyConverter {
public static String XML_SOURCE = "http://rss.timegenie.com/forex.gz";
public static long LAST_UPDATE=0;
private static SQLiteHelper.DatabaseAdapter dbAdapter;
private final static String TBL_NAME = "tbl_currency";
private final static String KEY_CODE = "code";
private final static String KEY_DESC = "description";
private final static String KEY_RATE = "rate";

private final static void createOrOpenDB(Context context) {
    SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper();
    TableObjectMaker tableObjs = dbHelper.new TableObjectMaker();
    tableObjs.addTable(TBL_NAME, new String[] {
             "_id integer primary key autoincrement",
             KEY_CODE + " text not null",
             KEY_DESC + " text not null",
             KEY_RATE + " real not null"
             });
    dbAdapter = dbHelper.new DatabaseAdapter(context);
    dbAdapter.open(tableObjs, "local_data", 1);
}
private final static void writeToDB(NodeList nodes) {
    if (nodes==null) return;
    List<ContentValues> content = SQLiteHelper.getContentValues(nodes,
            new String[] {KEY_CODE,KEY_DESC,KEY_RATE});
    for (ContentValues c:content) {
        dbAdapter.insertRowInTable(TBL_NAME, c);
    }
}
private final static void closeDB() {
    dbAdapter.close();
}
public static void updateDB(Context context) {
    Document xmlDocument = GZip.getResourceAsXML(XML_SOURCE,true);
    NodeList nodes = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("data");
    createOrOpenDB(context);
    writeToDB(nodes);
    closeDB();
    LAST_UPDATE = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}
...
}
```

The other class has identical database access/write methods as above, except with its own table name and field names, and it uses the same "local_data" name for the database name.
How can I get both classes to read and write to their own table in the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all access to the data base into a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Each class can then interact with the ContentProvider, which then interacts with the database.

Comment: Hi Ted, I see that a ContentProvider is a way of allowing other apps to use the same database, but is a ContentProvider still necessary if I am only accessing the database from different classes within the same app?

Comment: @user1031312 - No, it's not necessary. I suggested it because it might simplify your code to separate the database interactions into a separate component of the app.

Comment: I've already done that with my SQLiteHelper class. I also read a tutorial on the ContentProvider but it seems as so a contentprovider only creates one table, and I would need to create a separate contentprovider class for each table. So I'd rather create a different database name (which i'm doing for now) than use contentproviders.